# Google Play services failed to compile with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

I tried to compile a library with Gradle with its *gradlew.bat* file but it keeps failing. 
It shows the following message:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':library'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':library:_debugCompile'.
>   >
>   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          com.google.maps.android:library:0.3-SNAPSHOT

I already modified the gradle file to point it to the right direction:

```
List myDependencies = ["com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36",
        fileTree (dir: 'c://Program Files/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/3.1.36/', includes: ['*.jar'])]

dependencies {
    compile myDependencies
}
```

I have installed both Google Repository and Google Support Repository.

I use IntelliJ IDEA.

What else should I try?

Comment: Have you also included it as an external library in your project?

Comment: Usually an error like depends on the `buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }` part of the gradle file.

Comment: No, I used it outside my IDE. I just used its gradlew.bat file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied the *google-play-services.jar* file to my project and changed the *build.gradle* file to this:

```
dependencies {
   compile files('google-play-services.jar')
}
```

and it works okay now.